# How to create new vector based on a certain value in another vector?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have the following code:

```
set.seed(6)
round<-rep(1:6,2)
players<-rep(1:2, c(6,6))
decs<-sample(1:3,12,replace=TRUE)
game<-rep(rep(1:2,c(3,3)),2)
my_decs<-(c(0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,9))
gamematrix<-cbind(players,game,round,decs,my_decs)

        players game round decs my_decs
 [1,]       1    1     1    2       0
 [2,]       1    1     2    3       0
 [3,]       1    1     3    1       0
 [4,]       1    2     4    2       0
 [5,]       1    2     5    3       0
 [6,]       1    2     6    3       4
 [7,]       2    1     1    3       0
 [8,]       2    1     2    3       0
 [9,]       2    1     3    2       0
[10,]       2    2     4    1       0
[11,]       2    2     5    2       0
[12,]       2    2     6    3       9
```

Now, I want to create a new variable that is based for each participant on the "my decs" value in the last round, which is always 6.
I want the new variable to be the value of "my_decs" in the last round: so the final output should be:

```
         players game round decs my_decs new_var
 [1,]       1    1     1    2       0       4
 [2,]       1    1     2    3       0       4
 [3,]       1    1     3    1       0       4
 [4,]       1    2     4    2       0       4
 [5,]       1    2     5    3       0       4
 [6,]       1    2     6    3       4       4
 [7,]       2    1     1    3       0       9
 [8,]       2    1     2    3       0       9
 [9,]       2    1     3    2       0       9
[10,]       2    2     4    1       0       9
[11,]       2    2     5    2       0       9
[12,]       2    2     6    3       9       9
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Perhaps hastily, `gamematrix$new_var <- gamematrix$my_decs[ 6+6*((1:12 - 1) %/% 6) ]`. (I must add that this is rough and really can fall prey to all sorts of data anomalies. It would be much better to do something more reactive, as in "group by ... and find the last value".)

Comment: Extract the values from `my_decs` where `round == 6` and repeat these values six times: `rep(gamematrix[, "my_decs"][gamematrix[, "round"] == 6], each = 6)` (because there will always be six rounds if I understood you correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `tidyverse` package:

```
library(tidyverse)
gamematrix %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  group_by(players) %>% 
  mutate(new_var = tail(my_decs, 1))
```

Comment: There's also `last(my_decs)` in *dplyr*

Answer (score 2):

Consider using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
gamematrix <- as.data.table(gamematrix)
gamematrix[,new_var:=max(my_decs),by=players]
    players game round decs my_decs new_var
 1:       1    1     1    2       0       4
 2:       1    1     2    3       0       4
 3:       1    1     3    1       0       4
 4:       1    2     4    2       0       4
 5:       1    2     5    3       0       4
 6:       1    2     6    3       4       4
 7:       2    1     1    3       0       9
 8:       2    1     2    3       0       9
 9:       2    1     3    2       0       9
10:       2    2     4    1       0       9
11:       2    2     5    2       0       9
12:       2    2     6    3       9       9
```

Comment: Or `gamematrix[, new_var := my_decs[.N], by=players]` if it strictly has to be the last value regardless of whether it is the `max` or not.